# Ionic 2 Network Status with Ionic Native 3.X not working

Tags: networking, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to get network status in ionic2, Ionic-native docs example is not working: My code is:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
    @Component( {
        selector: 'page-network',
        templateUrl: 'network.html'
    })
    export class NetworkPage {

         Status: any = '';
         ConnectionType:any = '';

 constructor(private network: Network) { 
    let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
    this.Status = 'Disconnected';
      console.log('network was disconnected ');
    });
    disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();
    let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('network connected!');         
    this.Status = 'Connected';
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
          console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
        }
      }, 3000);
    });
    connectSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
 }
```

i have using ionic2. error not come but still it not working for me. Need to check if network status enable or disable.

Comment: it doesn't give any error or warning? none about cordova?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you `@ionic-native/core` is installed, and in `app.module.ts` add `Network` to the providers in `@NgModule` decorator, finally you must inject or call the created service in somewhere usually in `app.component.ts`

**Upadate**

Remove the unsubscribe method on the listeners

```
disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();
connectSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

I found out that you first `subscribe` to the network event then `unsubscribe`

Steps to make it work

1. Create ionic2 project
2. run the commands

   `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information`

   `npm install --save @ionic-native/network`
3. Add `Network` service in the `providers` array in the `app.module.ts`
   [image]
4. In `app.component.ts` use this code.

   [image]
5. Add the required platform lets choose `Android`

   `ionic platform add android`
6. Then run the code

   `ionic run android`
7. Finally try to enable/disable wifi and watch the console

Comment: how to create service in app.component.ts

Comment: You cannot create service in `app.component.ts`, just inject the service in app.component constructor

Comment: injected import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network'; still no response from service

Comment: @JamilHijjawi thanks for reply .We are getting this.network.type in android .Problem with IOS

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue this was how i solved it.
Make sure your

```
"@ionic-native/core": "~4.18.0",
```

and

```
"@ionic-native/network": "^4.18.0",
```

are the same version
by checking "@ionic-native/core" version on package.json in your project and installing 
"@ionic-native/network" with the same version of "@ionic-native/core" e.g if "@ionic-native/core" version is "4.18.0" then install "@ionic-native/network" of 4.18.0 version

```
npm install @ionic-native/network@4.18.0
```

It should work like that.